# Updating existing value (increase/decrease) compare old/new

Tags: apex, trigger

I have two objects :

```
Asset_line_item__c & Product2
```

Asset_line_item is a line item.

```
Asset_line_item:
Quantity__c

Product2:
Used_qty__c
```

I'm trying to update the `Used_qty__c` field in the Product object from `Asset_line_item`.

I'm little bit lost when it comes to how to check the existing quantity and if it is then add or minus and update the field (Used_qty__c) appropriately in the product2 object.

for an example:

if the user enters `quantity=5` and `used_qty__c` is `0` then the `used_qty__c` value should be `5`

the problem comes when:
if the user edit the same row and enter `quantity=4` and `used_qty__c` is now `5` but after update the `used_qty__c` should be `4`, why because the user enter the quantity=4, so in a sense that user can increase or decrease the qty.

Hope it clears.

Here is what I have tried.

```
public static void UpdateProductUsed(List<asset_line_item__c> alis, Map<Id, asset_line_item__c> oldMap)
{
      Set<Id> setAliIds = new Set<Id>();
     for(asset_line_item__c newAli : alis)
     {            
        asset_line_item__c oldAli = oldMap.get(newAli.Id); 
        if(newAli.Quantity__c != oldAli.Quantity__c) {
            setAliIds.add(newAli.Id);
        }
        //how do i find out if the qty is increase or decrease?
     }

     list<asset_line_item__c> ali_list  [select .... where ali in : setAliIds];

     List<Product2> updateProducts = new List<Product2>();
     for(asset_line_item__c r : ali_list) {

           /*this below two lines does not work correctly in the scenario 
            I have mentioned above where if the user edit the existing row
            and whether it increase or decrease the value then 
            I'm not sure how to handle that scenario 
            and I need help on that */
           Decimal used =  r.project__r.used_qty__c;
           decimal updatedUsedQty = (r.quantity__c + used);

           Product2 p = new Product2();
           p.Id = r.project__r.id;
           p.used_qty__c = updatedUsedQty;
           updateProducts.add(p);
     }  
     update updateProducts;
}
```

Comment: Few question. If you want both field in sync then why you need to check if qty is increased or decreased. Also you are updating parent based on child so you want to keep track of single child or sum of all child?

Comment: Can't you just use a roll-up summary?

Comment: So every product has used qty so for that reason I have to know which product I am updating the used qty field

Comment: I have' used before roll up summary so I am not sure

Comment: You can easily get that infomration from `r.project__r.id`

Comment: I tried that but the used_qty__c is getting null  in the first for loop

Comment: confirm you want the count of all quantity__c  on parent product?

Comment: Any thoughts why I be getting null all the time? Even though I have some values in it.

Comment: I want to update the used__qty__c in product by doing like this, (quantity + used qty)

Comment: Because in trigger you can't directly access parent field.

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to something like and make inner query and get all child quantity count and store that in parent. It will give you correct results.

```
     Set<Id> setAliIds = new Set<Id>();
     for(asset_line_item__c newAli : alis)
     {            
        asset_line_item__c oldAli = oldMap.get(newAli.Id); 
        if(newAli.Quantity__c != oldAli.Quantity__c) {
            setAliIds.add(newAli.project__c);
        }

     }

     list<Product2> ali_list  [select ..(Select quantity__c  from asset_line_item__r).. where ID in : setAliIds];

     List<Product2> updateProducts = new List<Product2>();
     for(Product2 r : ali_list) {
        Decimal used = 0;
        for(asset_line_item__c  as : r.asset_line_item__r)
        {
           if(as.quantity__c != null)
           used +=  as.quantity__c;
        }

           p.used_qty__c = used ;

     }  
     update ali_list;
}
```